# Out-of-line definition error on a class but it is declared in the header file

Tags: c++, xcode, cocos2d-x

Now this is a weird problem. I was coding two days ago and stopped and then continued just now. On my header file (`Fruit.h`) I added a method called `animateGrow()` like so:

Fruit.h:

```
class Fruit {
private:
   // Member variables here

public:
   // Other methods here
   void animateGrow( );
};
```

But when I try to add the same method in the CPP file, I get an `Out-of-line definition of 'animateGrow' does not match any declaration in 'Fruit'` error. It's declared in the header but Xcode does not seem to be able to find that method.

Fruit.cpp:

```
#include "SimpleAudioEngine.h"
#include "Fruit.h"
#include "Tree.h"

using namespace cocos2d;
using namespace CocosDenshion;

Fruit::Fruit( ) {
   // Constructor
}

// Getter Methods
// Setter Methods
// Other Methods

void Fruit::animateGrow( ) {
   // I get an error here when I type it.
}
```

**Full Code**: (links removed)
(In the code, the `Tree` class exists and all other methods and functions are working fine except for the `animateGrow()` as it gives me the error)

Comment: You should close the question, as its usefulness for future users is limited to none. Glad you fixed it, and good luck.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas How do I close a question? Sorry, I'm not familiar with this.

Comment: Uhm... is there not a link below the tags? (It might be that you need some reputation to do that... if the link is not there, don't worry, someone else will close it --I already voted to close, it just needs a couple more votes :)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Oh, there's no close link, just share, edit, delete, and flag. Thanks :)

Comment: I disagree - I came here today looking for a solution to the exact same error message, and there are 6 upvotes on this question. Propose it is re-opened.

Comment: I bumped into this exact problem when renaming class and header files (decided to cvt. objC to cpp rather than wrapping).  I couldn't figure out what was going on since my header file looked OK, but I got the error. Re-starting Xcode was all it took. This post saved me a lot of time!  Thanks @Lance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fixed it.

I don't know why but Xcode did not save my changes on the header file. I closed Xcode and opened the header file and the changes aren't there. I added the methods again and saved. I opened the CPP file added the new method in it worked fine.

Really weird.

Comment: After being reopened Xcode appears to be OK in my case :)

Comment: I had the exact same error message on BSD using clang. Your answer made me look at the header for my code, sure enough, I didn't declare the func in the header. Thanks!

Comment: I wanna say it helps me.Thanks

Comment: boom, bang! debugging someone's speghetti code and got this weird error,  worked defined class in header, solved.